# Number of undirected trees with $k$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, trees

If the number of undirected trees with $k$ vertices on a vertex set $V=\{1,\dots,k\}$ is $f(k) = k^{k-2}$ and the number of those who don't contain the edge $1-2$ is $(k-2)^{k-3}$, then why is the number of undirected trees with $n$ vertices containing the edge $1-2$: $g(k) = 2k^{k-3}$  ?

Comment: Note I'm seeking combinatorial proof

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Fixed that

Comment: Not sure about this result ? ... but see some of the ideas here ... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562757/prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-binomn-1k-kk-1-n-kn-k-1-nn-1-nn/3562788

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, every possible edge is in the same number of spanning trees, and each spanning tree contains exactly $k-1$ edges. Use this and the fact you cited to conclude.

Comment: I didn't understand this, may you explain further, the number of trees with K vertices is $K^{k-2}$  But why the number of those who contain the edge 1-2 is multiplied by 2/k?

Comment: Have you heard of double counting? The number of edges in all spanning trees is equal to the number of spanning trees multiplied with the number of edges per tree, but also equal to the number of distinct edges multiplied by the number of trees each edge appears in. You know three of those four numbers.

Comment: I’m very sorry, but no. This seems like homework and there’s honestly nothing more I can say without doing it for you...

Comment: I'm asking why we multiplied by 2 and then by 1/k, you are answering a different question, I'm not looking for math proof....

Comment: J.G.  Just so you know, since you didn't answer it fully for them, they reposted the dupe, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729424/how-to-explain-the-following-relation).  That's not said to fault you, but to let you know your instincts were correct as reflected in your comments above.

Comment: @amWhy I appreciate the heads up! My answer went from +1 to -1 along with the spammed comments, at which point I looked at some of the user's previous questions and got a better sense of what's going on here. I don't particularly care about the points, but at the end of the day, I still really would like the user to understand this problem (if only to stop reposting it on this site), but I honestly don't know how to say more without doing their homework for them, which was probably the whole point of this entire interaction...and with that, looks like their account and alt are gone/suspended.

Comment: Glad to have assisted.  I know your intent is always pure.  Unfortunately, a few users just want someone to do their homework. But worst, get belligerent when an answerer doesn't do their bidding.  Best of luck!