# An identity may related to binomial identity or Stirling formula.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, polynomials

I am trying to prove the following identity:
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}i^{i-1}(k+1-i)^{k-i}=2k(k+1)^{k-1}$. I tried with induction on $k$ but the main difficulty that it is hard to reduce the case of hypothesis assumption since $k$ contained both in the sum and inside of the sum. Could anyone please let me know how to deal with this case or any reference related to this kind of identities? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have a look at this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562757/prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-binomn-1k-kk-1-n-kn-k-1-nn-1-nn/3562788#3562788

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Thank you very much for your reference. Oh, it is in the book: Proof from the book but I did not remember.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: I rewrite LHS as follows: $(k+1)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\binom{k}{i}i^{i-1}(k+1-i)^{k-i-1}$, then the power of $k+1-i$ does not match with relatively the relation with the other terms as in the formula: $\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} k^{k-1} (n-k)^{n-k-1}=n^{n-1}-n^{n-2}$. Could you please let me know some more information on this? Thanks.